Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationask$
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.


A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
Android resource linking failed
aapt2.exe E 12-18 00:00:00 16612  8460 LoadedArsc.cpp:94] RES_TABLE_TYPE_TYPE entry offsets overlap actual entry data.
aapt2.exe E 12-18 00:00:00 16612  8460 ApkAssets.cpp:149] Failed to load resources table in APK 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-35\android.jar'.
error: failed to load include path C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-35\android.jar.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 18s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            259.1s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
i need solution for the problem
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.


A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
Android resource linking failed
aapt2.exe E 12-18 00:00:00 16612  8460 LoadedArsc.cpp:94] RES_TABLE_TYPE_TYPE entry offsets overlap actual entry data.
aapt2.exe E 12-18 00:00:00 16612  8460 ApkAssets.cpp:149] Failed to load resources table in APK 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-35\android.jar'.
error: failed to load include path C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-35\android.jar.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 18s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            259.1s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
